# Find gunicorn log file in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, gunicorn

I have a docker container running a python service with gunicorn. This is how the service was started :

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:6435 --certfile=cert.pem --keyfile=key.pem --ssl-version=5  --ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH app:app -w=5 --timeout=500 --daemon`

But, i am unable to find log files for the 5 workers. What would be the default path to find these log files?

I tried using the find command `find / -type f -name "hs_err_pid"` since these are the default file names gunicorn saves the log files with. But this gives me the following permission errors:

```
    find: ‘/proc/1/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/16/map_files’: Operation not permitted
find: ‘/proc/89/map_files’: Operation not permitted
```

Any way to find out the log files?

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to add `--access-logfile YOUR_FILE` to your command to specify a file or redirect it to stdout using `-`. the same goes for error logs.

see [this](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, thats what we are doing for the new deployment, just wanted to check if we could get the previous logs

Comment: for the error logs : Changed in version 19.2: Log to stderr by default. so docker logs should be the place to see them. I think

Comment: there is no syslog folder in /var/log/ :(

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. nothing there also which would have these logs

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it via a shell script.

```
gunicorn --chdir myapp myapp.asgi:application \
    -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
    --name apipa \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:5555 \
    --access-logfile - \
    --error-logfile -
```

If you are using a gunicorn config file

```
gunicorn your_app.wsgi:application -c /path/to/gunicorn.conf.py
```

with contents of the gunicorn.conf.py as

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5555"  
accesslog = "-"  
errorlog = "-"
```